# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tor Stack Exchange](http://tor.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is browsing with Tor safe against non government entities?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/is-browsing-with-tor-safe-against-non-government-entities)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Website blocking Tor Traffic](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/website-blocking-tor-traffic)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Should I run fast Tor relay or a stable relay is fine?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/should-i-run-fast-tor-relay-or-a-stable-relay-is-fine)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Default relay bandwidth?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/default-relay-bandwidth)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are get variables encrypted when using Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/are-get-variables-encrypted-when-using-tor)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Unable to connect to Tor network using TLS](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/unable-to-connect-to-tor-network-using-tls)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Tor hidden service bandwith question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/tor-hidden-service-bandwith-question)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [I need help downloading Tor browser](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/i-need-help-downloading-tor-browser)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [When I use Tor, I can't log in to Baidu](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/when-i-use-tor-i-cant-log-in-to-baidu)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How does one setup a Tor hidden service on android](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/how-does-one-setup-a-tor-hidden-service-on-android)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 1):

Right now it's kind of confusing where this site stands.  Is this site where all Tor-related questions should be asked?  Tor encompasses quite a lot.

- If your Apache server isn't showing your hidden service, does that go here or at ServerFault?
- If you want to know about the feasibility of using JavaScript utilities on your service, do you ask here or at Webmasters?
- If you're writing a script that proxies through Tor, do you ask for code help here or at StackOverflow?

If the answers to the above are "here", then these other sites should be putting up redirects.  It happens often enough on the main tiers that something will get bumped from the generic SO to something more specialized.  If the answers to the above are the other sites, then what is the purpose of this one?  Is there a mission statement regarding what kinds of questions should be asked?